# How to extract number of days from seconds_to_period function in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I put number of second into seconds_to_period() function and here is my code:

```
my_time_sum <- seconds_to_period(my_time_seconds_sum)  # Convert seconds to Period
my_time_sum
```

Output:

```
[1] "144d 12H 53M 19S"
```

I was just curious how can I extract '144' out of this string? Also, are there any ways to convert this duration to number of years?

Answer (score 2):

The `day()` function (and related lubridate unit functions `year()` etc.) have  methods for `Period` class so you can use:

```
library(lubridate)

day(my_time_sum)
[1] 144
```

Answer (score 1):

Just carry out an integer division. ie:

```
my_time_sum <- seconds_to_period(10000000)
my_time_sum %/% days(1)
[1] 115
```

If you want to convert to number of years, divide by years: ie

```
my_time_sum /years(1)
[1] 0.3168809
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract individual components using `$` like this:

```
my_time_sum$day
```

You can extract `$year`, `$month`, `$day`, `$hour`, `$minute`, and the confusingly-named `$.Data` for seconds.